# Why Is This Assembly Generated?:

Tags: assembly, x86-64

After executing `gcc -m64 -O test.c -save-temps`, I noticed that:
`mov     %edi, %edi`
appears in the generated assembly. Does this instruction even do anything? It moves `%edi` into itself, effectively accomplishing nothing.

All optimization levels produce this assembly, though in some cases it is placed differently.

Please let me know if you need me to provide further context. As of posting this question, I don't feel that further context is necessary, but I could be incorrect.

Code of procedure:

```
 subl    $400, %edi
 cmpl    $20, %edi
 ja      .L4
 mov     %edi, %edi
 jmp     *.L11(,%rdi,8)
```

This is referencing a jump table for a switch statement.

C Source:

```
int main()
{

}

int thing(int x)
{

   switch(x)
   {
        case 400:
        return  1;
        break;
        case 404:
        return  2;
        break;
        case 408:
        return  3;
        break;
        case 412:
        return  4;
        break;
        case 416:
        return  5;
        break;
        case 420:
        return  6;
        break;
   }

}
```

Comment: Try a higher optimization level? `-O2`?

Comment: Actually, can you show more of the assembly around that instruction? (including the addresses)

Comment: Hmm... can you also show the source for this snippet?

Comment: I have updated my question with additional information.

Comment: Updated with C source. Please note: This is not for practical use. We are studying the code strategies of jump tables generated by GCC at my university. I have not tagged this as homework, because this question in no way assists me in completing my assignment. I just don't understand why this instruction is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 64-bit mode, the `mov` instruction when used on 32-bit registers will zero the upper 32-bits of the destination register.

So:

```
mov %edi, %edi
```

clears the top 32-bits of `rdi`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOV_%28x86_instruction%29 (scroll all the way down)

Comment: Doh! I should have realized. Thank you for your help. It's taking me awhile to adjust to this architecture.

Comment: I was suspecting this from the beginning, but I had trouble finding a source for it. Then when you posted the source (with no 64-bit values) it became clear.

Comment: I'll just extend this by saying that **all** the 32-bit instructions in 64-bit mode clear the upper (63-32) bits of the respective registers. Source : Intel Optimization Guide, chapter 9.2.1 "Use Legacy 32-bit Instructions When Data Size Is 32 Bits".

Comment: Why is that necessary? The `subl` would already have cleared the upper bits right?

Comment: @harold It *could* be just an artifact of optimization. Or perhaps there's a jump to that location. (which seems somewhat likely since it's a switch with a jump table)

Comment: If there was a jump to it, the offset would be wrong and the range check skipped.. that doesn't make a lot of sense to me

Comment: You're right. Hard to tell without the assembly for the entire switch statement.